# Sue does vs Sue likes

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Are all sentences correct? I have the first one in my grammar book.

> I don’t like hot weather, but Sue does.

vs

> I don’t like hot weather, but Sue likes.

vs

> I don’t like hot weather, but Sue likes it.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "like" needs an explicit object.  So the second isn't used, except ironically (pretending to speak bad English as a joke).

The third is grammatically correct, but the first is the best way to express this.

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence is not idiomatic, as *likes* requires an object. The third is acceptable, but the first is the most idiomatic. Compare:

"Do you like hot weather?"

"I *don't*, but Sue *does.*